# Binary Search written in python with O(n)

Tags: python-3.x, complexity

```
def search(nums, target):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == target:
            return i
        if nums[i] == None:
          return -1
```

I think this code will be good for most cases in binary search but in some cases might need a better version of the code that is `O(log n)`.

Comment: This is not a binary search, this is a linear search, which is almost the opposite of binary search. Calling this "binary search" is very misleading.

Comment: So what exactly is your question here?

Comment: Is nums such that `0 <= i <= j < len(nums)` implies `nums[i] <= nums[j]` ?

Answer (score 11):

It's not really a binary search if it is not `O(log(n))`.

Binary search only works on sorted inputs and it takes advantage of the fact that it is sorted to achieve logarithmic complexity.

So it's quite the opposite - your version will be significantly inefficient for almost all programs that could use true binary search instead.

See, for example, [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=Binary%20search%20python)
how to implement binary search in python

Answer (score 1):

`search([2, None, 3], 3)` will return -1, and I think users will find this unexpected.
That is, the function doesn't just search, it has an added effect of returning -1 when it finds a `None` value.

The recommended way to check if a value is `None` is using the `is` keyword: `if value is None:`

When using both the index and the item during an iteration, the `enumerate` function is practical.

```
def search(nums, target):
    for index, num in enumerate(nums):
        if num == target:
            return index
       
    return -1
```